# how to make the file uploading to ftp faster

Tags: java

we are using  below code to upload files back to the FTP server?
basically 60 MB file is taking 3 minutes to upload to ftp server.Is there any way to make it faster?Please note that uploadable file(input file) and ftp server, both are on the same host but still its taking this much time.

at this line client.storeFile(filename, fis) its taking maximum time.

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
    client.login("admin", "secret");

    //
    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
    //
    String filename = "sample.zip";
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    //
    // Store file to server
    //
    client.storeFile(filename, fis);
    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a Java problem; have you tested the connection upload and download rates to/from the server? In my working experience, a 60MB file can take a minute or two to upload to a server, so it isn't out of the realm of possibility that you are limited by your connection speed rather than the execution speed of Java.

Comment: I don't know java, but some servers limit the ftp speed. Check and see if it allows multiple connection. If yes, you may consider upload chunks:
https://www.example-code.com/java/ftp_large_file_upload.asp

Comment: What gives same transfert from a dedicated client (Filezilla or command line ftp)? If it still takes 3 minutes, then the problem is not Java side...

Comment: split the file and send it in parallel

Comment: Manually when i upload(drag) a file to FTP folder through filezilla then  it's not taking this much time.